# Executing CURL statements in PHP after a particular time period

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl statements in my php code and I want them to be executed after a particular time period has passed. I have tried with the following code but it is not working:

```
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
```

What else can work instead of this??

Comment: you have tried for time out , not for recursive calling

Comment: Please describe the situation because I sense that you should take a different approach to this

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
function exe_fun(){

  // call curl here

 sleep(20); // wait 20 seconds
 exe_fun(); // call this function again
}
```

`curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);` is not for setting time interval but it is for setting expire time of response.